# Using a Java map safely as mutex holder

Tags: java, parallel-processing, thread-safety

Requirement is, that relevant code within method A is not executed in parallel on any Object with the same class.

Will following pseudo code do it?

```
 private final Map<String, Object> simpleMutex = new HashMap<>();
 
 public void A( final Object o)
  {
    final ThreadLocal<Object> myLock = new ThreadLocal<>();
    synchronized ( simpleMutex )
    {
      myLock.set( simpleMutex.computeIfAbsent( o.getClass().getName(), className-> new Object() ) );
    }

    synchronized ( myLock.get() )
    {
      System.out.println("Executing A on " + o);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private final Map<Class<?>, Object> locksMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void A(final Object o) {
     Object myLock = locksMap.computeIfAbsent(o.getClass(), className -> new Object());
     synchronized (myLock) {
          System.out.println("Executing A on " + o);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was reading Javadoc of ConcurrentMap which explicitly states that computeIfAbsent is not thread safe. But with ConcurrentHashMap it is!